# My modularizeImports in next.config.js is not working

Tags: next.js13

Version `"next": "13.5.4",`

I have a component that is importing these statements

```
import { Card, CardActions, CardMedia, Button, Typography } from '@material-ui/core/';
import {ThumbUpAlt, ThumbDownAlt} from '@mui/icons-material/';
```

These are the contents of my next.config.js file

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  modularizeImports:{
    '@mui/icons-material':{
      transform:'@mui/icons-material/{{member}}'
    },
    '@material-ui/core':{
      transform:'@material-ui/core/{{member}}'
    }
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

From what I understand, it's suppose to retrieve the specific modules I imported and not all however it's still importing all. When I run `npm run dev` I'm getting the following (11606):

[image]

However if I change my imports to

```
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ThumbUpAlt from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpAlt';
import ThumbDownAlt from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbDownAlt';
```

And run `npm run dev`, I'm getting (688):

[image]

Which is showing that my `modularizeImports` is not working. Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it's working now. I made a mistake and forget to include the `\` which is included in my imports. It's working now. The modified next.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  modularizeImports:{
    '@mui/icons-material/':{
      transform:'@mui/icons-material/{{member}}'
    },
    '@material-ui/core/':{
      transform:'@material-ui/core/{{member}}'
    }
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```